In 1979 was there a difference between citizenship of the UK and Colonies and British citizenship?
In 1979, was there any difference between

citizenship of the United Kingdom and Colonies (CUKC) and

the kind of citizenship that was held by a person classified as a "British subject with citizenship", which was the status held by most people who lived in Britain?


I have referred to this webpage published by the British government. This explains as follows:

Until 1949, nearly everyone with a close connection to the United
Kingdom was called a ‘British subject’.
All citizens of Commonwealth countries were collectively referred to
as ‘British subjects’ until January 1983. However, this was not an
official status for most of them.
Since 1983, very few people have qualified as British subjects.

Further on, that document refers to those who were classified as British subjects from 1983 who had until then been British subjects without citizenship. If I understand correctly, since 1983 the fullest kind of British nationality has been referred to simply as British citizenship (previously British subjecthood with citizenship), and British subjecthood is now another classification that comes with fewer rights.
My question is whether in 1979 the fullest kind of British nationality, namely British subjecthood with citizenship - as was held for example by most people who were born in Britain of British parents - was referred to as citizenship of the United Kingdom and Colonies (CUKC), or whether on the contrary CUKC was something different that perhaps was only obtained in the colonies?
If the two citizenships were different, what was the difference?

What's the significance of 1979?

@Greendrake - It has a personal significance for the individual for whom I'm asking. I doubt the answer would be different for 1978 or 1980 but given that I don't know what the answer is, it could be.

Key point: British citizenship does not necessarily give the right to live and work in the UK. You need the right to abode to do that.

British nationality law - Post-imperial redefinition of nationality classes: CUKCs were reclassified in 1983 into different nationality groups based on their ancestry, birthplace, and immigration status: CUKCs who had right of abode in the United Kingdom became British citizens while those connected with a remaining colony became British Dependent Territories citizens (BDTCs). Remaining CUKCs who were no longer associated with a British territory became British Overseas citizens.

@user71659 British citizenship does necessarily give the right to live and work in the UK because all British citizens have the right of abode.  Not all people with right of abode are British citizens, however.

@user71659. You are mistaken. All British citizens have the right of abode in Britain. You may perhaps be confusing British citizenship with British nationality. But this isn't related to the topic of this question.

No, BOC and BOTC don't come with right to abode, but they are clearly "British" and "citizen". It was only dealing with the Hong Kong situation did they put "national" in with BN(O).

@user71659 British Overseas citizenship and British Overseas Territories citizenship have the words "British" and "citizenship" in their names, but they are distinct from "British citizenship."  A British Overseas citizen is not a British citizen, nor is a British Overseas Territories citizen.


If I understand correctly, since 1983 the fullest kind of British nationality has been referred to simply as British citizenship (previously British subjecthood with citizenship)

"With" or "without citizenship" here doesn't refer to UK citizenship; it refers to any (Commonwealth) citizenship.  More precisely, from the government page linked in the question, a British subject without citizenship was one "who did not become a citizen of the UK and Colonies, a Commonwealth country, Pakistan or Ireland."  For example, in 1979, a Canadian citizen was a British subject, was not a Citizen of the UK and Colonies, and was not a British subject without citizenship.
Accordingly, the term "British subject with citizenship" does not denote "the fullest kind of British nationality," assuming that this phrase is intended to capture the nationality of the United Kingdom.  The official term for that nationality was "Citizenship of the United Kingdom and Colonies," although, as its name indicates, it included colonial populations in addition to the people the UK.


My question is whether in 1979 the fullest kind of British nationality, namely British subjecthood with citizenship - as was held for example by most people who were born in Britain of British parents - was referred to as citizenship of the United Kingdom and Colonies (CUKC), or whether on the contrary CUKC was something different that perhaps was only obtained in the colonies?

CUKC was the primary nationality of people in the UK as well as in the colonies.  From the British Nationality Act 1948:

12 British subjects before commencement of Act becoming citizens of United Kingdom and Colonies
(1) A person who was a British subject immediately before the date of the commencement of this Act shall on that date become a citizen of the United Kingdom and Colonies if he possesses any of the following qualifications, that is to say—
(a) that he was born within the territories comprised at the commencement of this Act in the United Kingdom and Colonies, and would have been such a citizen if section four of this Act had been in force at the time of his birth;

I have omitted much text relating to other circumstances; this should give the general idea.  For someone born after the act took effect, and also for full understanding of 12(1)(a), see section 4:

4 Citizenship by birth
Subject to the provisions of this section, every person born within the United Kingdom and Colonies after the commencement of this Act shall be a citizen of the United Kingdom and Colonies by birth[.]

I omit a couple of provisions relating to the children of diplomats and of enemy aliens in occupied territory.
In short, the concept you seem to be interested in was called CUKC -- indeed defined as such by statute -- not "British subject with citizenship"; that was actually a broader category that included almost everyone in the Commonwealth.

Note that there is an incorrect sentence in the government page linked in the question:

However, this was not an official status for most of them.

In fact, the 1948 act contains, indeed starts with, a definition of the status of "British subject":

1 British nationality by virtue of citizenship
(1) Every person who under this Act is a citizen of the United Kingdom and Colonies or who under any enactment for the time being in force in any country mentioned in subsection (3) of this section is a citizen of that country shall by virtue of that citizenship have the status of a British subject.
(2) Any person having the status aforesaid may be known either as a British subject or as a Commonwealth citizen ; and accordingly in this Act and in any other enactment or instrument whatever, whether passed, or made before or after the commencement of this Act, the expression " British subject " and the expression " Commonwealth citizen" shall have the same meaning.
(3) The following are the countries hereinbefore referred to, that is to say, Canada, Australia, New Zealand, the Union of South Africa, Newfoundland, India, Pakistan, Southern Rhodesia and Ceylon.

That's nothing if not official.

Finally, to respond to the title question:

In 1979 was there a difference between citizenship of the UK and Colonies and British citizenship?

By now you probably realize that there was no such thing as "British citizenship" in 1979; it was created in 1983 when the Nationality Act 1981 took effect.  Similarly, at the same time, CUKC ceased to exist, with most CUKCs having ties to the UK becoming British citizens.

"British subject with citizenship" is not really a recognized term, although "British subject without citizenship" is. That's because after 1948, the historical term "British subject" was reformed to take account of the new functioning of the Commonwealth, where different nations each wanted to have their own nationality and immigration law. The 1948 version is that the pre-existing legal status of "British subject" (which you could achieve by being born in the UK or elsewhere in the Empire - anywhere owing allegiance to the monarch) was to be fissioned into multiple independent citizenships. The UK and each of

Canada, Australia, New Zealand, the Union of South Africa, Newfoundland, India, Pakistan, Southern Rhodesia and Ceylon
(British Nationality Act 1948, s.1(3))

would have their own concept of "citizen", with the UK version "Citizen of the United Kingdom and Colonies" applying to the UK itself and its remaining overseas possessions. Anybody with any of those citizenships would be treated as a "British subject" by the existing law.
This neat plan was not what precisely happened, and there's still a cohort of people who are British subjects (because of their pre-1948 status) having not obtained any of the citizenships. That's what's meant by being a "British subject without citizenship". So, to be a "British subject with citizenship" is a bit ambiguous because the implications are different -

If you mean "someone who is a British subject by virtue of being a CUKC", then this is the same as a CUKC.
If you mean "someone who is a British subject by virtue of being a citizen of any of the countries", then that is not the same. Commonwealth citizens get a better deal than other foreign nationals, though.

Most people in Britain would have been CUKCs simply by virtue of being born there. Others may have had the status by descent, or been able to opt in because of long-term residence in the UK or a colony. People born in colonies were also CUKCs, but the system was administered locally and so there could be some divergences in law and practice in certain territories as to how the status could be obtained. The term CUKC definitely encompassed your category of people born in Britain with British parents.
This all changed in 1981 with the introduction of the category "British citizen". Most people born in the UK after 1 January 1983 are British citizens rather than being CUKCs. Already-living CUKCs were reclassified into either being British citizens (for most UK-born people) or else dependent-territories or overseas citizens (for the rest). This law, the British Nationality Act 1981, also tidied up the "British subject" status into its current residual form. Meanwhile, immigration restrictions had already made a distinction between some CUKCs and others, on essentially these lines. The 1981 Act was harmonizing the citizenship status with the existing rules (since the Immigration Act 1971) on right of abode.
